# Java enum list iterator issue

Tags: java, enums, iterator

```
package example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class anaBolum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<IMeyveler> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Muz());
        list.add(new Elma());

        Iterator it = list.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            it.next().fiyat() //compile error
        }
    }
}
```

I was use `list.iterator()` to access the list elements. But I can't access this method `fiyat()` in the iterator because I get compile error.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Too much of this question is in some local language. Try to internationalize it translating to English the names of methods and variables.

Comment: try the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700717/how-to-iterate-through-an-array-list

Comment: Also you should have precised that both Muz() and Elma() objects have the fiyat() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are getting some compile time error. If so You need to change the iterator declaration to `Iterator<IMeyveler> it = list.iterator();`

Other wise the iterator will not know the type of objects handled by it.

```
public class anaBolum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IMeyveler muz = new Muz();
        muz.fiyat();// Work

        ArrayList<IMeyveler> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Muz());
        list.add(new Elma());

        Iterator<IMeyveler> it = list.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(it.next().fiyat());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this

```
    while(it.hasNext()){
        Object obj = it.next() ;
        if( obj instanceof Muz ) {
          Muz muz = (Muz) obj ;
          muz.fiyat();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CodeCompletion does not show up, because `.next()` returns an `object` and not `IMeyveler`. You will either have to cast, or iterate differently.

```
    System.out.println(((IMeyveler)it.next()).fiyat());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
package javaaa;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class anaBolum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IMeyveler muz = new Muz();
        muz.fiyat();// Work

        ArrayList<IMeyveler> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Muz());
        list.add(new Elma());

        for(IMeyveler fruit : list)
        {
            if(fruit instanceof Muz)
            {
                System.out.println(fruit.fiyat());
            }
        }  
    }
}
```