# iterate through ArrayList<T> java?

Tags: java, android

I'm learning `Android` and `Java` i have created a class let's say like this

```
 class x(){
    public int a; 
    public string b;
 }
```

and then i initiate a list of this class and then added values to its properties like this

```
public ArrayList<x> GetList(){

List<x> myList = new ArrayList<x>();

    x myObject = new x();
    myObject.a = 1; 
    myObject.b = "val1";
     mylist.add(x);

    y myObject = new y();
    myObject.a = 2; 
    myObject.b = "val2";
     mylist.add(y);

return myList;
}
```

**My Question is how can i loop through what GetList() return**

*i have tried*

```
ArrayList<x> list = GetList();
Iterator<x> iterator = list.iterator();
```

but i don't know if this is the right way of doing this, plus i don't know what to do next i have added a breakpoint on the Iterator but it seemed to be null , the list have values thought

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Comment: @JigarJoshi for(X myx : GetList) that was outstanding Thanks ...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the very basics of a language

Comment: I seriously doubt that you could not find an answer to that question with a minimal search

Comment: @njzk2 i found some examples that uses Iterator but they were really complicated though

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700717/how-to-iterate-through-an-array-list-arrayindexoutofboundsexception is the first link when searching `iterate arraylist java` in your favorite search engine...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1. A `for` loop
2. Using the `iterator` method.

#### `for` loop:

```
for(x currentX : GetList()) {
    // Do something with the value
}
```

This is what's called a "for-each" loop, and it's probably the most common/preferred method of doing this.  The syntax is:

`for(ObjectType variableName : InCollection)`

You could also use a standard `for` loop:

```
ArrayList<x> list = GetList();
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
     x currentX = list.get(i);
     // Do something with the value
 }
```

The syntax for this is:

`for(someStartingValue; doSomethingWithStartingValue; conditionToStopLooping)`

#### `iterator` method:

```
Iterator<x> iterator = GetList().iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    x currentX = iterator.next();
    // Do something with the value
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can loop through your array with a for-each loop:

```
for (x item: GetList()) {
    doSomethingWithEachValue(item);
}
```

Comment: Clear and concise. Genius!

Answer (score 3):

I guess you can iterate through the arraylist a number of ways. One way is the iterator:-

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

al.add("C");
al.add("A");
al.add("E");
al.add("B");
al.add("D");
al.add("F");

System.out.print("Original contents of al: ");
Iterator<String> itr = al.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
  String element = itr.next();
  System.out.print(element + " ");
}
```

Another way would be a loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    list[i].a = 29;
}
```

Hope this helps in any way.

Ref

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_iterator.htm

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/arraylist/arraylist-in-java-example-how-to-use-arraylist/

*UPDATE*

I thought that I should just put this out there from research due to the comment below about performance.

**The Android docs**

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html

states:

> The enhanced for loop (also sometimes known as "for-each" loop) can be used for collections >that implement the Iterable interface and for arrays. With collections, an iterator is >allocated to make interface calls to hasNext() and next(). With an ArrayList, a hand-written >counted loop is about 3x faster (with or without JIT), but for other collections the enhanced >for loop syntax will be exactly equivalent to explicit iterator usage.
>
> There are several alternatives for iterating through an array:

```
static class Foo {
    int mSplat;
}

Foo[] mArray = ...

public void zero() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mArray.length; ++i) {
        sum += mArray[i].mSplat;
    }
}

public void one() {
    int sum = 0;
    Foo[] localArray = mArray;
    int len = localArray.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        sum += localArray[i].mSplat;
    }
}

public void two() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Foo a : mArray) {
        sum += a.mSplat;
    }
}
```

- **zero**() is slowest, because the JIT can't yet optimize away the cost of getting the array length once for every iteration through the
  loop.
- **one**() is faster. It pulls everything out into local variables,
  avoiding the lookups. Only the array length offers a performance
  benefit.
- **two**() is fastest for devices without a JIT, and indistinguishable
  from one() for devices with a JIT. It uses the enhanced for loop
  syntax introduced in version 1.5 of the Java programming language.

So, you should use the enhanced for loop by default, but consider a hand-written counted loop for performance-critical ArrayList iteration. Also this is stated by ***Josh Bloch's Effective Java, item 46.*** The iterator and the index variables are both just clutter. Furthermore, they represent opportunities for error.

The preferred idiom for iterating over collections and arrays

```
for(Element e : elements){
    doSomething(e);
}
```

Josh also states when you see the colon : read it as "In". The loop reads as for each element e in elements. I do not claim this work as my own even though I wish it was. If you want to learn more about efficient code then I suggest reading Josh Bloch's Effective Java.

Comment: Nice answer! Welcome to SO.

Comment: i'm new to java and from the link in the comment looks like iterate is not the best way of doing this type of task?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html States there are two basic rules for writing efficient code:

Don't do work that you don't need to do.
Don't allocate memory if you can avoid it.

However at the end of the day your the programmer. Do whichever you feel your comfortable at. @MinaGabriel

Comment: `Don't do work that you don't need to do` such as creating an iterator to loop on a List, you mean?

Comment: The link I gave states: The enhanced for loop (also sometimes known as "for-each" loop) can be used for collections that implement the Iterable interface and for arrays. With collections, an iterator is allocated to make interface calls to hasNext() and next(). With an ArrayList, a hand-written counted loop is about 3x faster (with or without JIT), but for other collections the enhanced for loop syntax will be exactly equivalent to explicit iterator usage. Again I just think it depends, but for this situation yes. If you think otherwise, it will be interesting to know your experience. @njzk2

Comment: I usually don't care about that kind of performance until I need to. Having clean code and avoid indices where it is not absolutely necessary is better imho. The fast enum syntax is better at carrying the notion of `for each item` than the indexed syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
class x {
    public int a;
    public String b;
}


private void test() {
    List<x> items = getList();
    for (x item: items) {
        System.out.print("val: " + item.a);
    }
}

private List<x> getList() {

    List<x> items = new ArrayList<x>();

    x oneObject = new x();
    oneObject.a = 1;
    oneObject.b = "val1";
    items.add(oneObject);


    x anotherObject = new x();
    anotherObject.a = 2;
    anotherObject.b = "val2";
    items.add(anotherObject);

    return items;
}
```