# How would I get all the words from a list that begins with the specified letter

Tags: java, input, applet

I am trying to show the list of words which start with the letter specified by the user input.

So for example if I add three words to my list, cat, corn and dog, and the user inputs the letter c, the output on the Java applet should be cat, corn.

However, I have no idea on how to go about this.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if (e.getSource() == b1 ){
        x = textf.getText();
        wordList.add(x);
        textf.setText(null);
    } 

    if (e.getSource() == b2 ){
    }
}
```

`b1` is adding all the user input into a secretly stored list, and I now want to make another button when pressed to show the words that start with the specified letter by the user.

```
textf = my text field
wordList = my list I created
x = string I previously defined
```

Comment: How do you declare `wordList`?

Comment: List<String> wordList = new ArrayList <String>();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through all the possible indices, check if the element at that index starts with the letter, and print it if it does.

**ALTERNATIVE (and probably better) code** (I was going to put this after, but since its better it deserves to be first. Taken form @larsmans's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700717/arrayindexoutofboundsexception-when-iterating-through-an-arraylist).

```
//given wordList as the word list
//given startChar as the character to search for in the form of a *String* not char
for (String element : wordList){
    if (element.startsWith(startChar)){
        System.out.println(element);
    }
}
```

**DISCLAIMER**: This code is untested, I don't have much experience with `ArrayList`, and Java is more of a quaternary programming language for me. Hope it works :)

```
//given same variables as before
for (int i = 0; i < wordList.size(); i++){
    String element = wordList.get(i);
    //you could remove the temporary variable and replace element with
    //  wordList.get(i)
    if (element.startsWith(startChar){
        System.out.println(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: would this actually print it out in an applet though, because thats the main problem i'm having

Comment: Well, I don't really use applets so you would have to find that out for yourself. You could make a new text field and add the words to it. I'm pretty sure `System.out.println` works on applets. You could always just try.

Comment: yeah i'll just find a way because nothing prints but I know the code is right because I did something like that before but nothing happened. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String prefix = "a";
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        l.add("aah");
        l.add("abh");
        l.add("bah");

        for(String s: l) {
            if(s.startsWith(prefix)) {
                result.add(s);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(result);
   }
```

**Result** is -

```
[aah, abh]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Java 8 then you can build in features to filter your list:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("cat");
    list.add("corn");
    list.add("dog");
    System.out.println(filter(list, "c"));
}

private static List<String> filter(final Collection<String> source, final String prefix) {
    return source.stream().filter(item -> item.startsWith(prefix)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This uses the [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) method to filter each list item which starts with the String of the `prefix` argument.

The output is:

> [cat, corn]